# Can we play .vtt file in android for subtitles?

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player, srt, webvtt

I have got a .SRT file working on Android platform as sub-tiles along with video. But the company has .vtt files for tons of videos, and .srt for only a few. .vtt is supported by iPhone development.

Can we play .vtt file on Android for subtitles? I have got .SRT files
working on Android.
If .vtt is not supported then we need to convert all .vtt files to the
.srt files.

Comment: did you manage to get it work?

Answer (score 2):

You can check http://caniuse.com/#feat=webvtt

Android supports webvtt from 4.4 or Chrome 38, so if you manage to have a web page that plays the videos with webvtt, you have the support of .vtt subtitles.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the information and in fact its useful to me. But I am playing video directly using android native video player not on any webpage. so you help me out for android native stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Yes of course , you can use vtt subtitle files in android but you should specify what player you use? like exo player , vlc , etc.. but it is supported in the most of player also if it isn't supported you can use library to convert it from vtt to srt